# Trouble with proof of arbitrary family of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Having a lot of trouble stringing together a proof for this.$B$ be arbitrary.Given index sets by $C_{b}=B-\{b\}$

(a)$\bigcup\limits_{b\in B}C_{b}=$?
(b)$\bigcap\limits_{b\in B}C_{b}=$?
(b)$\bigcap\limits_{b\in B}C_{b}=\emptyset$

Proof: $\bigcap\limits_{b\in B}C_{b}\supset\emptyset$

True vacuously since assuming an element in $\emptyset$ is false.

$\bigcap\limits_{b\in B}C_{b}\subset\emptyset$

Assume $a\in \bigcap\limits_{b\in B}C_{b}$.

Then $a \in C_{b}$ for all $b \in B$

$a \in B-\{b\}$ forall $b \in B$

$\uparrow$ Having trouble deciding what to do here.

part(a)If $|B|=0$ or $|B|=1$

then $\bigcup\limits_{b\in B}C_{b}= \emptyset$

$\bigcup\limits_{b\in B}C_{b}\supset \emptyset$ is trivial

$\bigcup\limits_{b\in B}C_{b}\subset \emptyset$

Assume $x \in \bigcup\limits_{b\in B}C_{b}$

then $x \in C_{b}$ for some $b \in B$

$\uparrow$ Having trouble deciding what to do here.

If $|B|>1$

then $\bigcup\limits_{b\in B}C_{b}=B$

Now I do not know how to finish the last part of this proof because I do not know where to start. Can I get some pointers?

Comment: For (b), take $b=a$ and see what happens.

Comment: Is this the proper syntax to complete part b.Let $a=b$, then $a \in B-\{a\}$ a contradiction that $a\in C_b$?

Comment: Did you mean why taking $b=a$ is a valid way of reasoning?

Comment: Sorry now I'm confused I deleted that last comment $a=B-\{a\}$ since it did not sound correct to me.You are saying that I need to use $a=B-\{a\}$ in the proof?

Comment: What I mean is we can derive $a\in B-\{a\}$ by taking $b=a$. This is possible as $b$ is arbitrary.

Comment: the last comment you said that you deleted, what were you trying to say, it sounded important?

Comment: To repeat, you have asked which reasoning is needed: proof by contradiction of just assert $b=a$ and done. I have answered the former one is adequate for the intersection case. However, I have also mentioned the latter one also needed to your last statement.

Answer (score 1):

(b)

If $a\in B\setminus \{b\}$, it follows that $a\in B$.

But $a\in B - \{b\}$ for all $b\in B$, thus if $a\in B$, then $a\in B - \{a\}$. A contradiction.

(a)

If $|B|=0$ then $B=\emptyset$, since that's the only set without elements. Since there are no elements, there are also no $C_b$, and thus the union of those sets is the empty union (the union over the elements of the empty set). But the empty union gives the empty set.

If $|B|=1$, then $B$ has exactly one element $b_1$, that is, $B=\{b_1\}$.
Then there exists exactly one $C_b$, which is $C_{b_1} = B-\{b_1\} = \{b_1\}-\{b_1\} = \emptyset$. The union of just one set is the set itself, which is $C_{b_1}=\emptyset.$

If $|B|>1$, there exist at least two elements $b_1\ne b_2\in B$. Then we have
$\bigcup_{b\in B} C_b \supset C_{b_1}\cup C_{b_2}$. Now prove that the union on the right hand side is $B$. Together with $\bigcup_{b\in B} C_b \subset B$, which is easy to prove, you get the desired relation.

Answer (score 0):

A.  If x in $\bigcap\limits_{b\in B}C_{b}$,
for all b in B, x in C$_b$.
Thus x in C$_x$, a contradiction.
Consequently $\bigcap\limits_{b\in B}C_{b}$ is empty.

B. For multipoint B, clearly $\bigcup\limits_{b\in B}C_{b}$ subset B.
If x in B, exists b in B with x in C$_b$,
Thus x in $\bigcup\limits_{b\in B}C_{b}\ $.
Consequently B subset $\bigcup\limits_{b\in B}C_{b}$.

Comment: For the union partB. should I say $x\in B$then consider $b \neq x$ since $x \in C_b$ for this $b \in B$ then it is in the union?